# PHP Variable Scope issue?

Tags: php, function, global-variables, scope

I'm writing a function and it uses the $PDO variable in another file.  I included the file at the beginning, but it's saying undeclared variable.  I'm assuming it's because it's out of scope.

```
  require './db/db.php';
  session_start();

    function createUser($username) {

    }
```

What can I do to be able to reference the variable $PDO which is my PDO instance to use the database in my functions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't declare the "PDO instance" inside any external function or class, you should just pass it to the function as a parameter. So (if you're talking about your `createUser` function)

```
createUser($PDO, $username) { }
```

And you'd call it like this: `createUser($PDO, 'Foo');`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass $PDO as an argument;

```
function function_name($PDO)
{
    // Your function code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the variable to the function as an argument, or put

```
global $PDO;
```

in the function.